Getting 404 error with React + Flask on EC2 using prod URL
I am running a Flask + React app on EC2 using Vite. Everything is running fine on when I run 'npm run dev' as you can see here . Its also running fine from the flask end as you can see here . The issue is when I try to run it using my prod server with my ec2 url or even when I run 'npm run build' and 'npm run preview'. I get the following when i run these commands. Also, when I type in my ec2 url, i get this. and when I type in 'ec2-url/api/hello', i get the same console error but my page shows the classic 404 message: 'Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. '
Anyways, this is what my app.py looks:
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# Set up logging
if not os.path.exists('logs'):
    os.mkdir('logs')
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/myapp.log', maxBytes=10240, backupCount=10)
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
))
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app.logger.info('MyApp startup')

@app.route('/')
def hellodefault():
    app.logger.info('Hello endpoint was accessed')
    return jsonify(message="Hello from default Flask Route!")

@app.route('/api/hello')
def hello():
    app.logger.info('Hello endpoint was accessed')
    return jsonify(message="Hello from Flask!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


This is what my App.jsx looks:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const apiUrl = `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/api/hello`;
    console.log('VITE_API_URL:', import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL);
    axios.get(apiUrl)
      .then(response => setMessage(response.data.message))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{message}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

I have two .env files in my frontend directory where my react project is. one is called .env.development and contains: 'VITE_API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:5000'
my .env.production currently contains 'VITE_API_URL=http://ec2-xxx-amazon.com'. my vite.config.js is:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})



Just double checking, can you access anything at all exposed on your EC2? If you don't get any endpoint, it's possible you haven't allowed access via your security group.

yea, my inbound rules allow IPv4 access from http and https from any source (0.0.0.0/0). and all outbound traffic allows to any source from all types of traffic.
